# I have a web app running inside a docker container, how do I access it on localhost?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a python flask web app running inside a docker container, how do I access it on my host?

When I run the up, it is ready and listening on port 5000 inside the container, but I want this exposed so I can access it
xxxsssddd  | 2020-04-23 19:28:48,416  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'

services:
    mywebapp:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: mywebabb.yml
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        networks:
            default:

        volumes:
            - .:/opt/mywebapp
```

Comment: It should be accessible on port 5000 on your host, since you bind port 5000 in the host to port 5000 in the container.

Comment: You can see " * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ " copy that and paste where you want.